# Service/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware] No CORS policy found for the specified request

Tags: azure, cors, identityserver4, serilog, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

This might be an already answered question but I have tried already what I have found on stackoverflow.

This is the problem:

No cors policy found, how to fix this?

Situation: I have an identity server 4 server, that allows external authentication (oidc), 2 external servers so far. One works fine the other one (Azure AD B2C) don't.

This is my startup class:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultCorsPolicyService> logger;
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddDapr();

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(opt => opt.IssuerUri = "http://tenant")
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.ApiResources)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
            /*var cors = new IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultCorsPolicyService(logger)
            {
                AllowAll = true
            };*/ //this didn't work

            services.AddSingleton<IdentityServer4.Services.ICorsPolicyService>((container) => {
                var logger = container.GetRequiredService<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultCorsPolicyService>>();
                return new IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultCorsPolicyService(logger)
                {
                    AllowAll = true
                };
            });

            /*services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });*/ //didn't work
            /*services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
                    );
            });*/

            AddServices(services);

            services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache();

            AddAuth(services);

            AddSwaggerGeneration(services);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error-local-development");
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Tenant v1"));
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCloudEvents();


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
        }

        private void AddServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<ITenantRepository, DaprTenantRepository>();
            services.AddSingleton<IDaprClientAdaptor, DaprClientAdaptor>();
        }
        private void AddAuth(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "TestIdentityServer", options =>
                    {
//...code for the first identity provider server, the one that works
                    })
                        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc3", "AzureInternalTestIdentityServer", options =>
                        {
                            options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                            options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
                            options.SaveTokens = true;


                            options.Authority = "https://my azure authority";
                            options.ClientId = "my clientId";
                            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                            options.Scope.Add("email");

                            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                            {
                                NameClaimType = "name",
                                RoleClaimType = "role"
                            };
                        });


            services.AddAuthorization();
        }

        private void AddSwaggerGeneration(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options => options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV");
            services.AddApiVersioning(options =>{
                options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                options.ReportApiVersions = true;
            });
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.EnableAnnotations();
                // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = @"JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. 
                      Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.
                      Example: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSU...'",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer"
                });

                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
                  {
                    {
                      new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                      {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                          {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                          },
                          Scheme = "oauth2",
                          Name = "Bearer",
                          In = ParameterLocation.Header,

                        },
                        new List<string>()
                      }
                    });
            });

            services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>, ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I am using app.UseCors, I have setup Serilog on program.cs, I don't know if that will impact it.

logs from docker (I am using docker and dapr):

```
2021-07-13T14:07:39.7018825+00:00 [INF][/Service/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5007/External/Challenge?scheme=oidc3&returnUrl=%2Fdiagnostics - -
2021-07-13T14:07:39.7093231+00:00 [INF][/Service/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware] Executing endpoint 'IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.ExternalController.Challenge (Tenant)'
2021-07-13T14:07:39.7141041+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker] Route matched with {action = "Challenge", controller = "External"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Challenge(System.String, System.String) on controller IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.ExternalController (Tenant).
2021-07-13T14:07:39.7455289+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult] Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (["oidc3"]).
2021-07-13T14:07:41.1914398+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler] AuthenticationScheme: oidc3 was challenged.
2021-07-13T14:07:41.2103318+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker] Executed action IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.ExternalController.Challenge (Tenant) in 1496.0595ms
2021-07-13T14:07:41.2115812+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware] Executed endpoint 'IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI.ExternalController.Challenge (Tenant)'
2021-07-13T14:07:41.2454932+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5007/External/Challenge?scheme=oidc3&returnUrl=%2Fdiagnostics - - - 302 0 - 1543.5567ms
2021-07-13T14:07:41.8513003+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics] Request starting HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:5007/signin-oidc application/x-www-form-urlencoded 427
2021-07-13T14:07:41.8578905+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware] No CORS policy found for the specified request.
2021-07-13T14:07:41.8630414+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware] No CORS policy found for the specified request.
2021-07-13T14:07:42.0976889+00:00 [ERR][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler] Exception occurred while processing message.

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The payload was invalid.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Managed.ManagedAuthenticatedEncryptor.Decrypt(ArraySegment`1 protectedPayload, ArraySegment`1 additionalAuthenticatedData)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.DataProtectionCommonExtensions.Unprotect(IDataProtector protector, String protectedData)
at IdentityServer4.Infrastructure.DistributedCacheStateDataFormatter.Unprotect(String protectedText, String purpose)
at IdentityServer4.Infrastructure.DistributedCacheStateDataFormatter.Unprotect(String protectedText)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.ReadPropertiesAndClearState(OpenIdConnectMessage message)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()

2021-07-13T14:07:42.6735507+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler] Error from RemoteAuthentication: The payload was invalid..
2021-07-13T14:07:43.1458887+00:00 [ERR][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The payload was invalid.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Managed.ManagedAuthenticatedEncryptor.Decrypt(ArraySegment`1 protectedPayload, ArraySegment`1 additionalAuthenticatedData)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.DataProtectionCommonExtensions.Unprotect(IDataProtector protector, String protectedData)
at IdentityServer4.Infrastructure.DistributedCacheStateDataFormatter.Unprotect(String protectedText, String purpose)
at IdentityServer4.Infrastructure.DistributedCacheStateDataFormatter.Unprotect(String protectedText)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.ReadPropertiesAndClearState(OpenIdConnectMessage message)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
at IdentityServer4.Hosting.FederatedSignOut.AuthenticationRequestHandlerWrapper.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

2021-07-13T14:07:43.2072371+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware] No CORS policy found for the specified request.
2021-07-13T14:07:43.2084321+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware] Executing endpoint 'TenantsService.V1.Controllers.ErrorController.ErrorLocalDevelopment (Tenant)'
2021-07-13T14:07:43.2205122+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker] Route matched with {action = "ErrorLocalDevelopment", controller = "Error"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult ErrorLocalDevelopment(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment) on controller TenantsService.V1.Controllers.ErrorController (Tenant).
2021-07-13T14:07:43.2723048+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor] Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails'.
2021-07-13T14:07:43.3656934+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker] Executed action TenantsService.V1.Controllers.ErrorController.ErrorLocalDevelopment (Tenant) in 145.0361ms
2021-07-13T14:07:43.3658905+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware] Executed endpoint 'TenantsService.V1.Controllers.ErrorController.ErrorLocalDevelopment (Tenant)'
2021-07-13T14:07:43.3662553+00:00 [INF][/TenantService/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics] Request finished HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:5007/signin-oidc application/x-www-form-urlencoded 427 - 500 - application/problem+json;+charset=utf-8 1514.9476ms
```

Comment: Share the error log. It is common for id server to spit out that message, but normally it won't cause your authentication to fail.

Comment: Most issues can be resolved if you enable debug in id server log.

Comment: can you do that in Azure? and how?

Comment: 'The payload was invalid' This is your clue..., do you have multiple servers? Are they using the same key?

Comment: It is a single identityserver4 server, that is supposed to accept multiple identity providers (one works), then, there are different services or Apis that are supposed to get the token. It is supposed to be a ledger, with multiple servers, at the moment there is only one node

Comment: If I remove the identity provider that works, azure b2c does not work either, so it is something to do with that provider

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe CORS is required here as the Oauth2/Open ID Connection mainly bounce around using HTTP redirects. and I am not sure exactly when CORS are required in Identity Server, maybe when you want to retrieve user info with the idtoken using ajax?

The thing with Azure AD B2C is that it gets a few additional parameters like sign in /out policy that I believe the normal OpenID Connect middleware cannot handle it well. I will suggest try to use MSAL library(Web.Identity.Web) to implement it. So rather than the AddOpenIdConnect call, you do

services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");

as shown here.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C/Startup.cs

Good luck!